# White space during animation in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my tableView I would like to extend the height of cell with animation. It works, but when I push it there is whitespace between extended cell and another cell. 
This happens with animation option

```
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
```

and only

```
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
```

is ok.

You can see it in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilo0_8d1UNM&feature=youtu.be).
Somebody can explain why it happens or suggest another solution? Thank you.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([self isSelectedCell:indexPath]) {
        return self.heightCellAnimation;
    }
    return HeightCommonCell;
}

- (void)changeHeightCellFor:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath inTableView:(UITableView*) tableView
{
    self.indexPathSelectedCell = indexPath;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];

        self.heightCellAnimation = [self getHeightForCurrentScrollView] + HeightCommonCell;
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x,
                                cell.frame.origin.y,
                                cell.frame.size.width,
                                self.heightCellAnimation);

        self.heighSelectedCell = indexPath.row;

        [self.tableView endUpdates];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because Apple uses `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut` for the `tableView`'s animations and because of that your animation looks *ok* once you use the same option.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think it can be reason of my problem. Do you know hot to change UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut for the tableView's animations to another one?
p.s. sorry for late reply